# iOS Pinch Zoom using MobileVLCKit

Tags: ios, libvlc

I am working on an iOS video live streaming app. I need to implement zoom in and out features with users getting an ability to pan the window to see the whole view. I am using `MobileVLCKit-Prod` for live streaming. Can anyone help me with how to achieve this? There doesnt seem to be any resource available for the same.